# How can I programmatically enable Gmail for new users using Admin SDK?

Tags: php, gmail, google-admin-sdk

I'm able to create new users in the Google Directory (using the Admin SDK for php), but I notice that when I log in as any of theses users, Gmail is not enabled.

Is there a way to add functionality to my code to enable Gmail for new users?

If this is helpful, here's the function I use to create the user

```
function createGoogleAccount($acc_user, $acc_password)
{
    $client = getClient();
    $service = new Google_Service_Directory($client);

    $userInstance = new Google_Service_Directory_User();
    $nameInstance = new Google_Service_Directory_UserName();

    $nameInstance -> setGivenName('Generic');
    $nameInstance -> setFamilyName('Account');

    $userInstance -> setName($nameInstance);
    $userInstance -> setHashFunction("MD5");
    $userInstance -> setPrimaryEmail($acc_user . '@sandbox.xxxxx.edu');
    $userInstance -> setPassword(hash("md5", $acc_password));
    $optParams = array( );

    $error_msg = null;
    try
    {
            $createUserResult = $service->users->insert($userInstance, $optParams);
            var_dump($createUserResult);
    }
    catch (Google_IO_Exception $gioe)
    {
            $error_msg =  "Error in connection: ".$gioe->getMessage();
    }
    catch (Google_Service_Exception $gse)
    {
            $error_msg = "Service Exception: ".$gse->getMessage();
    }

    return $error_msg;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do it programmatically, but what can I give you is this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users) for the things that you need to know about the new user. It is stated here that if a user was not assigned to a specific organizational unit when the user account was created, the account is in the top-level organizational unit. A user's organization unit determines which Google Apps services the user has access to. If the user is moved to a new organization, the user's access changes.

Comment: Thanks, KENdi. Actually, the account admin clarified this with me yesterday, so now I create users under a specific OU that he set up for this.

Answer (score 0):

As KENdi pointed out in his reply, the user has to be created within an organizational unit that has access to the needed Google app or service.
After clarifying this with the account admin, I was able to get it to work by adding the user under the correct OU.